# Loading multiple instances of the same linux driver which has EXPORT_SYMBOLS and globals

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a linux kernel driver which has a global variable which is accessed inside an EXPORT_SYMBOL function. The driver is re-entrant and will be loaded multiple times based on the device tree entry. I am trying to find a way, with which other kernel drivers identify individual instances so that they can set the callback with the correct driver instance.

For example inside my driver module:

```
    /*global variable */
    struct list *list;

    int foo(void * data, void *callback(void *data)) {
           //This function uses *list pointer.
    }
    EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo);
```

This driver can be invoked multiple times based on device tree entry.

Comment: You cannot load a module multiple times. You shouldn't be able to, `insmod` would error out saying it's already loaded. It doesn't make much sense either, what are you trying to do exactly that requires trying to insert the module multiple times? Be more specific and descriptive.

Comment: There is no way. You have the design level issue. Redesign your driver properly.

Comment: *"This driver can be invoked multiple times based on device tree entry."* -- Only if there are multiple instances of that device, and each one is uniquely addressable. Then the driver needs to be *re-entrant* (instead of loading multiple copies).

Comment: Yes the driver is re-entrant. I want other kernel drivers to be able to identify each instance of the device separately so that they can set a callback with individual instances.

Comment: Presumably, each device would have some private data allocated when your driver's device "probe" function is called, so the callback function pointer set by other kernel drivers can be stored in the private data for that device.

Comment: @IanAbbott I understand that part. But since the driver is re-entrant, the EXPORT_SYMBOL functions dont appear separately to the outside world. From my observation, I cannot control which instance of the re-entrant driver I am setting callbacks to. I want to be able to know which instance of the driver is which.

Comment: Your EXPORT_SYMBOL function that sets the callback would need an extra parameter to specify which device instance the callback is being registered for,. But you also need to provide a mechanism for the other driver to determine what value to use for that extra parameter.